# Are Trideva creator themselves or only corporeal of God(Ishwar)

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, brahma

As written in the title I want to know that what are Trideva(Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva)- Creator or corporeal of God(only).
Many people say that Trideva are creator themselves and other say that they are only corporeal of God.
For that I am quite confused. I think they are only corporeal of god like other Devas. What do you think about it?

Comment: Trideva are the Creator Himself who takes other forms to discharge his duty of Creation, Preservation and Destruction of the Universe. I will try to answer this question as far as possible. all the best and welcome.

Comment: No. Shree Maha Ganesha created Vishnu from Sattva Guna, Brahma from Rajas Guna and Shiva from Tamas Guna. Then the Trinity bowed down to Shree Mahodara Vinayaka and ShivaPutra Ganesha told them to Preserve, Create and Destroyer respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Creation**
>
> **In the beginning, there was nothing in the
>   universe. There was only darkness and the
>   divine essence (brahman).** It is impossible to describe the brahman, it has no traits that
>   can be described. When the time came for creation to start, the
>   brahman removed the darkness and divided
>   itself into three. **These three parts came to
>   be known as Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva.** The
>   first object that was created was water and
>   Vishnu slept on this water. Since nara means
>   water and ayana means resting-place, Vishnu
>   is accordingly also known as Narayana.
>   In this water next appeared a golden
>   (hiranya) egg (anda). The egg shone with the
>   radiance of a thousand suns. Inside the egg,
>   Brahma created himself. Since he effectively
>   created (bhuva) himself (svayam), Brahma is
>   also known as Svayambhuva. The egg, you
>   will remember, was golden. Garbha means
>   womb, and since Brahma was born inside a
>   golden egg, he is also known as
>   Hiranyagarbha.
>   For a thousand years Brahma stayed inside
>   the egg. He then split the shell into two and
>   emerged out. Heaven (svarga) was made
>   from one half of the shell and the earth from
>   the remaining half. All the land masses, the
>   oceans, the rivers and the mountains, had
>   been inside the egg in embryonic form.
>   Brahma made them manifest.
>
> **—[Matsya purana:creation chapter](http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/matsya_purana.php)**

same is asserted in vayu purana and kurma purana too.

Comment: What's up bro? you are not coming online since many days now..

Answer (score 0):

As per Srimad Bhagavad Mahapurana "In the beginning, there was nothing in the universe. There was only darkness. In the immense void if one looks closely into the depths, at the bottom of the dark ocean, Lord Vishnu is asleep on Sesha Naga. As the time for creation arises, the Lord awakens - in this Kalpa, from his navel sprouts a divine lotus on which is seated the Creator Brahma. He looks around to see what is their and as he looks around four heads of his sprout up one facing each direction. and as per Vishnu's instructions, Brahma begins the job of creation. As creation progresses Vishnu sees the growth of undesirable qualities and hence to maintain the balance He takes yet another form of the Destroyer Shiva."

Therefore the Trideva are Swayambhu i.e. self created and not born of any parents.

Comment: Hi Suresh ji , can you please explain how was there any concept of top or down when there was nothing ? you said "In the beginning, there was nothing in the universe. There was only darkness. In the immense void if one looks closely into the depths, at the bottom of the dark ocean, Lord Vishnu is asleep on Sesha Naga"
also , Vishnu is sleep , then what about the place , the ocean where he's sleep , who created that space ?